# The method and calculation for the total energy that two inductors,which has Mutual inductance, stored in this circuit

Tags: inductor, inductance, energy

The solution for the total energy that two inductors stored in this circuit is

\$E=\frac{1}{2}\times 4 \times 3^2+\frac{1}{2}\times 6 \times 6^2-1\times 3 \times 6=108J\$

I want to ask two things

1.Why is \$E=\frac{1}{2}\times 4 \times 3^2+\frac{1}{2}\times 6 \times 6^2-1\times 3 \times 6\$,i mean , \$\frac{1}{2}\times 4 \times 3^2\$ and \$\frac{1}{2}\times 6 \times 6^2\$ are both energy calculation because of  \$E=\frac{1}{2} L  I^2\$,but why does \$1\times 3 \times 6\$ is the energy calculation?it just the multiplication of  Mutual inductance and two different current,and there is no \$\frac{1}{2}\$ in it.

2.If i use this method to calculate the total energy that two inductors stored,the answer is wrong,why?

\$L_{eq}=\frac{L_1L_2-M^2}{L_1+L_2+2M}=\frac{23}{12}\$,then \$E=\frac{1}{2}LI^2=\frac{1}{2}\times\frac{23}{12}\times6^2=\frac{69}{2}J\$,why will i get the wrong answer if i use this method??

[image]

Comment: [This explains the math](https://www.globalspec.com/reference/81742/203279/9-6-energy-stored-in-a-pair-of-mutually-coupled-inductors).

Comment: No it isn't - I just visualize the wound turns on left winding sliding around the core to sit above the other winding. I hate it when you can't bloody rely on some (f)artist getting something as basic as this wrong.

Comment: @Andyaka Is the fig 9.13 correctly doted? " Next, we want the current in L2 to enter the end which will produce a flux in the same direction, in this case, clockwise. This will be accomplished if the current i2 in L2 enters the lower end as shown and thus we place a dot at that end." https://www.globalspec.com/reference/81741/203279/9-5-establishing-polarity-markings

Comment: Where are we drifting with this @G36???? See above comment before you deleted and reposted.

Comment: @Andyaka Nowhere. At least in the first edition, they got it right.  http://research.iaun.ac.ir/pd/naghsh/pdfs/UploadFile_4266.pdf (page 273)

Comment: Yes that is correct. You just can't get the staff.